# Explain some code which uses recursion and currying

Tags: scala

How is the method product used in this code ?

The result for this function is 3600

So product takes a function : f , 
f takes an Int parameter which returns an Int parameter.

But does (a: Int, b: Int) not indicate that a function which takes two Int parameters are returned ?

I'm confused as to what is is occuring in this line : 
f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)

Complete function :

```
 def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
    if(a > b) 1
    else {
     f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
    }                                        
  product(x => x * x)(3 , 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, methods can have multiple parameter lists. In this example, the method `product` has two parameter lists: `(f: Int => Int)` and `(a: Int, b: Int)`.

The first parameter list contains one parameter named `f`, which is of type `Int => Int` (a function that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`).

The second parameter list contains two parameters named `a` and `b` which are both of type `Int`.

The expressions `product(f)(a + 1, b)` and `product(x => x * x)(3 , 5)` simply call the method with all three parameters.

The advantage of this is that you can "call" `product` with only the first parameter list. What you'll then get is a function that you can call by supplying the second parameter list. For example:

```
val fn = product(x => x * x)  // only the first parameter list is applied
fn(3, 5)                 // fn is a function which you can pass the second list
```

"Calling" `product` with only the first parameter list is called **currying**.

Comment: >"Calling" product with only the first parameter list is called >currying.
may be "partial application"?

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko Yes, partial function application, I used the word "calling" (in quotes) to make it clear for someone who hasn't seen this before.

Comment: I think @SergeyPassichenko's point is that this isn't actually [_currying_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) or using _curried_ functions, but rather [_partially applying_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application) a function or using a _partially applied_ function. Take a look at [`Function5`'s `curry` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function5.html)—it actually returns a new function of type `(T1) ⇒ (T2) ⇒ (T3) ⇒ (T4) ⇒ (T5) ⇒ R`, which is true currying.

Comment: Is there a way in the recursion, to use the partial application or do you have to always pass in all the parameters as in the question `product(f)(...)`?

Comment: @Pykler: I would also like to know this!  Because what if, for instance, your partial application has a long parameter list and you don't want to have to write them all out again!

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés its been a while since I jumped into Scala, I think you can pass the partial to a function.